# Try statement not working

Tags: java, try-catch

My try statement is not working properly, it says I need finally statement,
I have no idea what that is. [1st part of code[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qltiZ.png)

[2nd part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI887.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM4Sr.png)

Someone please just tell me what is going wrong. It is supposed to read from a text file using the filereader.

Comment: Edit your question please. Show the entire `try-catch`, and not a link to a photo but a well-formatted code.

Comment: I have added the edits. Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a `catch` statement to follow the `try{}`?

Comment: where would I put that?

Comment: Alright I have added the catch statement, but when it tries to read the file, all I get is 12 null values. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hard to tell. Your code seems fine to me. What does the `SWAG` file contain? Are you sure it does not have any extension, like `.txt`?

Comment: I am doing this on a mac, so is there a specific way to read a file on mac? Also it just contains 12 string values and i used textedit so it is .rtf extension.

Comment: Specify `.rtf` when opening the file with `new FileReader()`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use multiple catch blocks for a single try block or you can have only one finally block for the try block. But you must specify atleast one catch block or a finally block for the try block. Use the following syntax:-

```
try{
   //your statements...
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(or)

```
try{  
    //code that may throw exception  
}finally{

}
```

For more clarification, go through the following link:-
https://www.javatpoint.com/try-catch-block

i hope it is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    try {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {

    }
```

finally block is not necessary in most case.
I suppose you miss the catch statement in your code